# how to flatten a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

i was making a hand, and then i realized that it looks low-poly, so i subdivided it by 2, and this was the result:[image]

i searched google but i only found `loopTools` add-on and it doesn't work with my case
so how can i fix this??

thanks :)

Comment: Hello how did your mesh look like before you subdivided and how did you subdivide? Do it with the Subdivision Surface modifier, not right click > Subdivide, on a round object it won't be good

Comment: i subdivided it using the right click in the edit mode, bec. when i was applying  subdivision surface modifier blender crashes(i think bec of the rigging and bones)

Comment: why don't you want your hand to be low-poly?

Comment: i don't know, it doesn't fit the other game models

Comment: maybe show your topology before subdividing, and also show the rest of the topology, or even share your file

Comment: here is the [link for the files](https://filebin.net/078a328d8gzfcii0)

Comment: The topology is not good, you need to redo the arm as well, use quads, not tris, I guess the mesh will be made of tris when imported into a game engine but when you work on it it needs a quad topology

Comment: what is the quad topology? ok but first i want to smooth this fingers, do you have any way for this? then i will redo all the rigging and bones

edit: it is not necessary to make this hand perfect, anything will be good :)

Comment: If you do a right click >Shade Smooth in Object mode, it will smooth the shading, but it won't make the topology better, for a good topology for the hand, watch some tutorials?

Comment: i think that the hand was already smooth shaded